# Q objects in filter **arguments

Tags: python, django, filter

When I query in Django and the query depends on filters I always do something like this:

```
            if country:
        country_arguments = {"country": country}
    else:
        country_arguments = {}

    if supplier:
        arguments = Q(supplier=supplier) | Q(supplier__parent=supplier)
    else:
        arguments = ""
```

Now I need a Q() in that argument. The argument should be something like this:

```
    if country:
        country_arguments = {"country": country}
    else:
        country_arguments = {}

    if supplier:
        arguments = Q(supplier=supplier) | Q(supplier__parent=supplier)
    else:
        arguments = ""

    sites = (
        sites.filter(
            arguments,
            **country_arguments,
        ).all())
```

But I get an error:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

How can I do it as an **argument like:

```
arguments = Q(**{"supplier": supplier}) | Q(**{"supplier__parent": supplier})
```

Comment: You could try `Q(**{"supplier": supplier})`. Does that help?

Comment: That helps, but how do i do the I (or statement)

Comment: the filter should do "all sites with that supplier and all sites with that supplier as parent"

Comment: Think I got it:
arguments = Q(**{"supplier": supplier}) | Q(**{"supplier__parent": supplier})
will test this, thanks!

Comment: Seems good to me. But IMHO, when you have to specify the keyword name anyway, you can just write: `arguments = Q(supplier=supplier) | Q(supplier__parent=supplier)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if country:
    query = Q(supplier=supplier) | Q(supplier__parent=supplier)
else:
    query = Q()
    
sites.filter(query).all()
```

The best way would be to remove the `else` clause:

```
sites = Site.objects.all()
if country:
    query = Q(supplier=supplier) | Q(supplier__parent=supplier)
    sites = sites.filter(query)
```

Comment: Is the "Q(pk__gt=0)" not a bit odd?

Comment: @sg_sg94 yes it is. The best way would be to query all before the `if`, then filter and remove the `else`